# Which D&D 3.0 & 3.5 Kingdoms of Kalamar books are considered officially licensed third-party products?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, product-identification, books

[Hey I Can Chan's answer to the question "How do you tell if a D&D book is 3.0 or 3.5?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/47190) describes a category of products as follows (emphasis mine):

> officially licensed Kingdoms of Kalamar **third party** products—products bearing some combination of the Dungeons and Dragons logo and the Wizards of the Coast officially licensed product seal or including on their title pages that the product is officially licensed by Wizards of the Coast.

Which D&D 3.0 & 3.5 Kingdoms of Kalamar books are considered officially licensed third-party products?

Comment: If it wasn't clear before, it should be now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Kingdoms of Kalamar

The history of [Kenzer & Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenzer_%26_Company)'s relationship with Wizards of the Coast is better handled by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28844/8610). To the best of my knowledge, all of the following products bore the Wizards of the Coast Official Licensed Product seal… at some point. It's entirely possible that titles are missing from this list or that dates are inaccurate; this information isn't as easy to come by as, for instance, information about [Dragonlance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158955/8610) or [Ravenloft](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158959/8610).

The Kingdoms of Kalamar Player’s Guide *v3.5 Adaptation* (Dec. 2003) updates feats from the *Kingdoms of Kalamar Player’s Guide* for the *3.5* revision, but some doubt lingers among fans about the *Adaptation*’s ability to change the *Player’s Guide*, *either* because the *Adaptation* doesn't itself bear the seal *or* because the *Adaptation* isn’t actually called errata. Ask the DM.

Eventually released was official *Player’s Guide* errata (2006), but it didn’t incorporate all the changes suggested by the *Adaptation*, and it was released after Kenzer & Co.'s license lapsed. Further, Kenzer and Company continued to publish Kingdoms of Kalamar material for the d20 system without the seal, including the *Player’s Guide to the Sovereign Lands* (2006), a *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* product that republished and changed again mechanics found in the *Kingdoms of Kalamar Player’s Guide*. This changed some of the earlier, more precarious game elements, but, because of their provenance,  these fixes may not apply in a official-material-only campaign. Ask the DM.

To show how complicated this is, the feat [**Irresistible Spell**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147617/8610) (*Kingdoms of Kalamar Player’s Guide* 87), for example, is updated by *Sovereign Lands*. And the feat [**Miser with Magic**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55116/8610) (*Kingdoms of Kalamar Player’s Guide* 88), for example, received errata, is changed by the *Adaptation*, *and* is updated by *Sovereign Lands*. Again, ask the DM. A lot.

- 2001/03 *Kingdoms of Kalamar Campaign Setting*
- 2001/04 *The Root of All Evil*
- 2001/06 *Coin's End*
- 2001/06 *Forging Darkness*
- 2001/06 *Midnight's Terror*
- 2001/07 *Harvest of Darkness*
- 2001/08 *Aldriv's Revenge*
- 2001/10 *Deathright*
- 2001/11 *Siren's Prize*
- 2002/02 *Lands of Mystery*
- 2002/03 *Geanavue*
- 2002/03 *Invasion of Arun’Kid*
- 2002/04 *Kingdoms of Kalamar Player's Guide*
- 2002/06 *Pekal Gazetteer*
- 2002/08 *Villain Design Handbook*
- 2002/12 *Fate of Heroes*
- 2002/12 *Fury in the Wastelands*
- 2002/12 *Lost Tomb of Kruk-Ma-Kali*
- 2003/02 *Strength and Honor*
- 2003/04 *Garden of the Plantmaster*
- 2003/07 *Dangerous Denizens*
- 2003/08 *Stand and Deliver*
- 2003/09 *Salt and Sea Dogs*
- 2003/11 *Secrets of the Alubelok Coast*<sup>1</sup>
- 2003/11 *Stealth and Style*
- 2003/12 *Kingdoms of Kalamar Atlas*
- 2003/12 *Loona*
- 2004/04 *Player's Primer*<sup>1</sup>
- 2004/05 *Blood and Shadows*
- 2004/07 *Friend and Foe: Gnomes and Kobolds of Tellene*<sup>1</sup>
- 2005/04 *Friend and Foe: Elves and Bugbears of Tellene*
- 2005/07 *Perils of Pekal*<sup>1</sup>
- 2005/09 *Black as the Brightest Flame*<sup>1</sup>

Some sources include among this material [***Goods and Gear***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1594590168) (July 2004) and [***By the Sword***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1594590494) (Nov. 2005), but—so far as I can tell—neither text ever bore the seal.

Keep in mind that I'm not a lawyer and that my use of semilegal terms like *license* and *lapse* are colloquial. They are not meant to question, challenge, minimize, or impugn the *actual* chain of events that occurred between Kenzer & Co. and Wizards of the Coast. I am merely a fan trying to make sense of a list of RPG books.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Texts so noted were originally released with the seal but later rereleased after the license lapsed *without* the seal. This may apply to other texts on the list also, but, despite this, I have been able to acquire with ease the other titles *with* the seal. That is, so far as I can tell, a product with this note *can't* be acquired in its original form (with the seal) from the publisher; only by purchasing the physical product on the secondary market can the version with the seal be acquired. An items so noted may also have a different release date if it bears the seal, but I don't know that original release date as I haven't seen a sealed version.

Comment: I can confirm the original release date for the following products: Secrets of the Alubelok Coast (2003), Friend and Foe: Gnomes and Kobolds of Tellene (2004), Perils of Pekal (2005), Black as the Brightest Flame (2005).

Comment: @Zarus As those years align with mine, I've to ask: Do they have the seal?

Comment: Why...yes, yes they do!

Comment: Player's Primer (2004), seal and date confirmed. All of your original release dates in the footnoted titles are correct.