# What books did WotC give Arthaus's official permission to publish?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, books

I'm looking for the titles that include Arthaus's Ravenloft with [this](http://www.thievesguild.cc/article/images/ravenloft.png) and [Arthaus's Warcraft: The Roleplaying Game?](http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/images/e/ee/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_%283rd_Edition%29.png)

Comment: HeyIcanchan asked if I could break these up into different questions.

Comment: I think this is a legit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ravenloft

Arthaus's Ravenloft game line in its entirety was produced under a license from Wizards of the Coast. That game line includes the following material:

#### Ravenloft material published for *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition*

- 2001/10 *Ravenloft Campaign Setting*
- 2001/12 *Secrets of the Dread Realms*
- 2002/04 *Denizens of Darkness*
- 2002/05 *Van Richten's Arsenal Volume I*
- 2002/06 *Gazetteer Volume I*
- 2002/08 *Heroes of Light*
- 2002/10 *Champions of Darkness*
- 2002/12 *Gazetteer Volume II*
- 2003/02 *Van Richten's Guide to the Walking Dead*
- 2003/04 *Gazetteer Volume III*

#### Ravenloft material published in light of the *3.5* revision

- 2003/07 *Ravenloft Dungeon Master's Guide*
- 2003/09 *Ravenloft Player's Handbook*
- 2003/13 *Gazetteer Volume IV*
- 2004/01 *Denizens of Dread*
- 2004/03 *Van Richten's Guide to the Shadow Fey*
- 2004/05 *Gazetteer Volume V*
- 2004/10 *Masque of the Red Death*<sup>1</sup>
- 2004/12 *Legacy of the Blood*
- 2005/05 *Dark Tales and Disturbing Legends*
- 2005/08 *Van Richten's Guide to the Mists*

Other material—including a DM's screen and a deck of not!tarot cards—may also have been produced, but these, to my knowledge, include no mechanics.

## Warcraft

Only *Warcraft* bears the Wizards of the Coast seal (on the back: "Official Licensed Product"). I have been unable to track down any controversy surrounding the presence of the seal on *Warcraft*, but no other book in the game's line bears the seal. Hence, technically, only the material from *Warcraft* is game-legal by default in a campaign that allows official material only. However, for completeness, the entire game line is as follows:

- 2003/07 [*Warcraft*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1588460711)<sup>2</sup>
- 2003/10 *Manual of Monsters*
- 2004/01 *Alliance and Horde Compendium*
- 2004/04 *Magic and Mayhem*
- 2004/07 *Lands of Conflict*
- 2004/10 *Shadows and Light*

All of these take into account the *3.5* revision. Keep in mind that some of these books include material that can unbalance a campaign. If you're tired of wizards in your campaigns getting stomped on all the time by overpowered fighters, for example, *Magic and Mayhem* is your book. (Look at the feats Hasten Spell (32) and Link Spell (*ibid.*), for instance.)

---

<sup>**1**</sup> This is, essentially a standalone but derived *d20 System* roleplaying game, about as compatible with *D&D 3.5* as *d20 Modern*.
<sup>**2**</sup> Link provided so that a reader doesn't get confused. This is the first iteration of *Warcraft* for the *d20 System*; later Arthaus would publish [*World of Warcraft: The Roleplaying Game*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1588467813), which is not licensed from Wizards of the Coast and is, essentially, a standalone but derived *d20 System* roleplaying game.

Comment: While I appreciate the subtle humor in your last paragraph, I'm concerned the uninitiated may mistake the threat of PHB fighters to wizards as an actual concern one might want to balance by giving Wizards the ability to cast all their spells at once instead of caring about the action economy.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Actually, that's serious… but most folks won't have that problem. Also, I presaged it with an actual warning ("Keep in mind that some of these books include material that can unbalance a campaign"). I'm not that concerned that a DM who's considering adding *Warcraft* material to his campaign will accidentally read that sentence in isolation and say—seriously—, "Finally! Tools that'll give wizards an edge over fighters!" Really, the game is now so analyzed that it takes only a cursory Web search to learn of the widely held opinion that wizards rule and fighters drool.

Comment: However, if your concern is great, I can dial back the humor. I mean, it's really a struggle for me because I'm such a wacky guy and all, but I can do it. `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Nay, do not dial back the humor! Too long hath my wizards been overshadowed by these..."overpowered fighters"! The time of reckoning is at hand!

Comment: Interesting, I tried to find more info about those two metamagic feats, but they're hardly ever discussed online. In fact, this answer is the only time that either of them have been mentioned under the 3.5e tag!

Comment: @J.Mini I am happy to contribute an answer to a question like *What's broken about the* Magic and Mayhem *metamagic feats Hasten Spell and Link Spell?* They're bonkers. (And it seems like Please stop being evil may be able to chime in, too.)

Comment: Don't worry about it, Hasten Spell is bonkers and I've got a pretty good guess what Link Spell will do.

Comment: @J.Mini Presumably independent of this question, an Aug. 2020 mention of the feat **Link Spell** occurs in [this thread](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?618169-3-XP-Multiple-dancing-weapons) in the Giant in the Playground forums. However, the user appears to be employing it for style not shenanigans.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I've found a description of them both, along with Greater Link Spell, at https://www.wowarchives.us/magic-mayhem/greater-link-spell-[metamagic.html They're blatantly bonkers. With Greater Link Spell, you can cast 100 level 5 spell at once, with only one level 6 spell slot!